# MERGE INTO triggering duplicate key value specified

Tags: db2-400

Table A has a simple structure:

```
ID
FOREIGN_ID
ORIGIN
```

There is a unique key over `FOREIGN_ID` and `ORIGIN` to prevent duplicates.

Table B has many fields, but of interest is

```
ORIGIN_ID
ORIGIN
```

Table B can have many rows with the same origin and origin_id.  My goal is to create an insert trigger on table B that will insert only unique `ORIGIN_ID/ORIGIN` combinations into table A.

But first, I need to make a working insert that will avoid inserting duplicates. When in the trigger, values from the row of Table B will be used rather than these hard-coded values

```
MERGE INTO MYLIB.TABLE_A AS TARGET
USING
        ( SELECT FOREIGN_ID , ORIGIN FROM MYLIB.TABLE_A ) AS SRC
        ON SRC . FOREIGN_ID = '123' AND SRC . ORIGIN = 'ABC'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ( FOREIGN_ID , ORIGIN ) VALUES ( '123' , 'ABC' )
```

The first time I execute the statement, it works as expected.  A row is added to table A.
The second time it is executed, I expect it to do nothing, with no errors.

But I get

```
[Code: -803, SQL State: 23505]  [SQL0803] Duplicate key value specified.
```

What am I missing or not doing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the way to hardcode a test merge...

You want to use a "Table Value Constructor" (TVC).

Try this (expanded to 2 rows so you can see how to use a TCV):

```
MERGE INTO MYLIB.TABLE_A AS TARGET
USING
  ( values ('123','ABC'),('456','DEF')) as SRC (FOREIGN_ID, ORIGIN)
on SRC.FOREIGN_ID = TARGET.FOREIGN_ID AND SRC.ORIGIN = TARGET.ORIGIN
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT ( FOREIGN_ID , ORIGIN ) VALUES ( SRC.FOREIGN_ID, SRC.ORIGIN );
```

Comment: I hadn’t imagined that approach, but it makes sense; limit the source table to exactly what you want to match. I’ll try that out as soon as I can